# Google chrome extension: When should we use the background script?

Tags: background, google-chrome-extension, notifications, desktop

I am a newbie to Google Chrome Extension.

I wanted to know, when should we use the background script?

```
"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }
```

Actually, I am developing an extension, which will display some message(via desktop notifications) at particular intervals. So I am using the setInterval() method inside the javascript file(this is not the background.js).

But it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone please explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: > So I am using the setInterval() method inside the javascript file(*this is not the background.js*).

Then add that JavaScript file to the "scripts" list.

Answer (score 1):

Background script is common for all tabs, and content script is separate for each tab.
It depends on scenario that what you want do.

Please have a look [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) for notification doc

Sample extension also available [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/notifications.zip)